# SpringSource bundle repository changing

Tags: spring, maven, osgi-bundle

It appears that SpringSource may be changing the location for hosting of their OSGI bundles?

Our Nexus repository manager has the following repositories defined:

- External Bundle Releases: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/
- External Library Releases: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external/
- SpringSource Bundle Releases: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/
- SpringSource Library Releases: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release/

However, when attempting to reference the following dependency, it does not appear to be available from any of these?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead, this appears to be in a new location: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle ??

Hope someone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the FAQ of EBR (Enterprise Bundle Repository), the [instructions for Maven](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q8) are to use exactly the settings you are using so you are doing everything right. Also, it's not like `repository.springsource.com` is moving to `ebr.springsource.com`, according to the FAQ these two are the same. Or better said, `ebr.springsource.com` is the web-facing searching tool, while `repository.springsource.com` is the actual Maven repository.

Related to the discrepancy between what you get from Maven and what you get in web page when searching is that there must be some bug in the web page that makes it not to be synchronized with the actual resources from the Maven repository.

Also, from the same [FAQ page](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q2) you should note that EBR is no longer actively maintained by 
SpringSource and the bundles in there are no longer up to date.

**UPDATE**: See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/23/spring-framework-3-2-and-the-springsource-ebr) about the decision to freeze EBR and not to publish Spring artifacts as valid OSGi bundles anymore.

Also, the most relevant details about your concern (related to version 3.2.5) are to be found at [this forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/513222/1220525/#msg_1220525) where Glyn Normington (committer to various OSGi related projects in SpringSource) specifically says that Spring 3.2.4 is the last version of Spring that will be officially released with valid MANIFEST headers in its artifacts:

> After a bit of discussion, we have decided not to publish Spring Framework 3.2.5 bundles to the SpringSource EBR and to keep it read-only.